# How is the principle/paradigm called that enables chaining from native objects?

Tags: javascript, syntax, language-agnostic, theory, syntactic-sugar

This may be a duplicate, because I cannot find the words in my head to even spur up a query.

On daily basis I am working with PHP, C#, JavaScript, though, only in JavaScript I am able to chain like a madman out of the box.

For instance, given a simple (I know it's somewhat vague) algorithm:

> Given an array of arbitrary values, transform the data to contain unique values multiplied by two that are greater than 6.

In PHP7, I could implement it like:

```
<?php
$initial = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, -1, -3, -5];

$multiplied = array_map(function ($v) {
    return $v * 2;
}, $initial);

$unique = array_unique($multiplied);

$matching = array_filter(function($v) {
    return $v > 6;
}, $unique);

var_dump($initial, $matching);

// Or this crazy variation.
$matching = array_filter(array_unique(array_map(function($v) {
    return $v * 2;
}, $initial)), function ($v) {
    return $v > 6;
});

var_dump($initial, $matching);
```

Though, JavaScript:

```
var filterUnique = function(value, index, collection) {
  return collection.indexOf(value) === index;
};

var initialData = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, -1, -3, -5];

var data = initialData.map(function(v) {
  return v * 2;
}).filter(filterUnique).filter(function(v) {
  return v > 6;
});

console.log(initialData.length, initialData)
console.log(data.length, data);
```

In C# there are loads of options.. With Linq being the easiest one that actually allows to perform operation in similiar fashion to JavaScript. Though, the underlying structure there is different.
Yet, if I wanted to go the hard way, I would face a similar situation like in PHP with explicit declarations and more due to the strict nature of C#.

What is this chaining principle/paradigm called?
What other languages can I find it in?

I tend to call it functional programming, but when reading up on functional languages, the description there is more generic than this... I'm looking to clear up my misconceptions on this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: Yes, but isn't that somehwat a special trait when found in language constructs by default?

Comment: Mate, I was just sharing a resource which I thought could be interesting to you.

Comment: You're not looking for words like *lambda expression* or *anonymous function*, are you? I always thought these sorts of things were loosely based on the *lambda calculus*, but then again so are functional languages.

Answer (score 0):

I work with PHP for years now and actually, the question of having TyeObjects is all but easy, especially when you begin to speak about comparison: Is Number(23) equal to 23, what about Int(23) vs 23.5, Int(0) vs 0, vs null...

For the little I know it caused a lot of trouble to Java(not script) developers when they implemented it.

So the most "obvious" way would be to implement the classes Int / Float or maybe Number to gather them, a class String, etc, and all the functions related. This is a real need of PHP but would be extremely time consuming.

Another solution, much more easy, is to consider that, as all functions are written in snake case / C style in PHP, and almost all methods are in camel case, you can create a pipe of calls like this

```
echo (new Pipe("my super cool string"))->strtoupper()->apply();
```

This would print

```
MY SUPER COOL STRING
```

And you can chain as much native functions call as you want.

In my case, my first need was to make some fluent calls asynchronously so it's called slightly differently and is first meant to call methods of objects but the following code would work with my lib:

```
$chainOfCalls = DefferredCallChain::new_("string")
    ->strtoupper()
    ->explode(' ', '$$')
    ->array_reverse()
    ->print_r();

$chainOfCalls("My string I want to modify");
// prints ['MODIFY', 'TO', 'WANT', 'I', 'STRING', 'MY']
```

It's available here: https://github.com/jclaveau/php-deferred-callchain

Concerning the paradigm categorization, first beware of the difference between functional programming / pure functional languages / functional syntax.

- Functional programming was just about using functions.
- Pure functional programming is a dedicated paradigm with only functions and no states (so less side effects). Lisp is a good example.
- Functional syntax is the way to write like in pure functional paradigm but in imperatives languages like PHP.

And actually, fluent (chained) syntax is just like functional syntax respecting gravity while reading (e.g. you begin to read at top left and finish at bottom right). And it's what seems to me the less brain consuming.

Hoping it answers your question :)